# Absolutely convergent doubles sums in Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

Let $X$ a Banach space and $x_{ij} : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to X$. Suppose $\sum_i \sum_j \|x_{ij}\| < \infty$. Then it is easy to show that the following series are convergent:
$$\sum_j x_{ij}, \sum_i x_{ij}, \sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}, \sum_j \sum_i x_{ij}.$$
Then I want to know if:
$$\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij} = \sum_j \sum_i x_{ij}.$$

This would be a direct corollary of a Fubini-Tonelli type theorem for Bochner integrals, but I can't find a reference on that. So if someone could point me to a reference to such a theorem for Bochner integrals, that'd be ideal (or let me know if/why such a theorem doesn't exist). But also a direct proof of the above would work.

Comment: I think you can just take $x^*  \in X^*$ and apply it to both sides in the last equation. Then a standard Fubini-Tonelly (to swap the real sums) is enough.

Comment: @gerw I'm not sure what you mean by "take $x^* \in X^*$". Only if $X$ is a Hilbert space, it'd make sense I think.

Comment: $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Dual_space

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith  How do we identify $x \in X$ with $x* \in X^*$ without an inner-product?

Comment: You don't need to.  $x^*$ is any arbitrary element of the dual space, unrelated to $x$.

Comment: I can prove that the proposition holds if $x_{ij} : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to X^*$. How do I prove it for $x_{ij} : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to X$?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I feel like we're not on the same page. How would the dual space help in proving the desired proposition?

Comment: Show $$x^*(\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}) = x^*(\sum_j \sum_i x_{ij}).$$

Comment: Ok makes sense. I got confused by the notation at first. But that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in X^*$ arbitrary. Then:
$$f(\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}) = \sum_i \sum_j f(x_{ij}).$$
Then $|f(x_{ij})| \leq \|f\| \|x_{ij}\|$, so:
$$\sum_i \sum_j |f(x_{ij})| \leq \|f\|\sum_i \sum_j \|x_{ij}\| < \infty.$$
Thus we can apply the standard result on reordering series (i.e. the corollary of Fubini-Tonelli), giving:
$$f(\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}) = \sum_i \sum_j f(x_{ij}) = \sum_j \sum_i f(x_{ij}) = f(\sum_j \sum_i x_{ij}).$$
Then since $f \in X^*$ was arbitrary, we have:
$$\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij} = \sum_j \sum_i x_{ij},$$
as desired.